# Split multidimensional array from SOAP response

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I hae vthe below code

```
<?php
  if (is_object($checkAvailability->availableHotels)) 
  $hotelResponse[] = $checkAvailability->availableHotels;
  $hotelResponse = $checkAvailability->availableHotels;
  foreach ((array)$hotelResponse as $hnum => $hotel)
?>
```

`$hotelResponse` is a Multi-dimensional array

```
print_r($checkAvailability->availableHotels); is generating :
```

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [processId] => H0-41925041 [hotelCode] => ITJHRV [availabilityStatus] => InstantConfirmation [totalPrice] => 1421 [totalTax] => 0 [totalSalePrice] => 1509.38 [currency] => EUR [boardType] => Breakfast Buffet [rooms] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [roomCategory] => Classic Double or Twin Room-1 queen bed [paxes] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) ) [totalRoomRate] => 1421 [ratesPerNight] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-20 [amount] => 203 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-21 [amount] => 203 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-22 [amount] => 203 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-23 [amount] => 203 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-24 [amount] => 203 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-25 [amount] => 203 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-26 [amount] => 203 ) ) ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [processId] => HA-51032431 [hotelCode] => ITRR5G [availabilityStatus] => InstantConfirmation [totalPrice] => 1590 [totalTax] => 0 [totalSalePrice] => 0 [currency] => EUR [boardType] => Bed & Breakfast [rooms] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [roomCategory] => Twin Room (Including Breakfast and Wi-Fi) [paxes] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) ) [totalRoomRate] => 1590 [ratesPerNight] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-20 [amount] => 197 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-21 [amount] => 197 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-22 [amount] => 239 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-23 [amount] => 239 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-24 [amount] => 239 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-25 [amount] => 239 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-04-26 [amount] => 240 ) ) ) ) ) )

How can i do that  get every response by echoing them as below

```
<?php echo $hotel->hotelCode?>
<?php echo $hotel->totalPrice?>
```

As i understand i need to convert the 2d array into a object but from there i have no clue. Please help.

Comment: i think `$checkAvailability->availableHotels` returns array...so why you are passing this to another 2D array `$hotelResponse[]` and how this will be an object?

Comment: Yes indeed its returning array. But i dont know how to convert it to object.

Comment: `$hotelObject = json_decode(json_encode($hotelResponse), FALSE);`

Comment: i have inserted the above line but still the same every time i echo <?php echo $hotel->hotelCode?> its returning only one value in all echos

Comment: you have changed your code for which ...the `$hotelResponse` will be always an array..not 2D. share the result of:       `print_r($checkAvailability->availableHotel)`

Comment: Its a quite long data. You may check them on https://www.bookingassist.ro/test/test.php

Comment: please check above the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$hotelCodes = array() ;
$availHotels = $checkAvailability->availableHotels ;
foreach($availHotels as $hotel){
    $hotelCodes[] = $hotel->hotelCode ;
    //echo $hotel->hotelCode ;
    //echo $hotel->totalPrice ;
}
```

Now you have `$hotelCodes` array and access it like `$hotelCodes[0]`, `$hotelCode[1]` and so more.

Comment: Thanks, now its echoing both values. But how can i ilotate them and use the responses separately in the page ?

Comment: can't get "*ilotate them*"...
would you paste the expected result you want now... ?

Comment: i mean to isolate each hotel code an use them separately in the page,: `var_dump($hotel->hotelCode);`` response is : `string(6) "ITRR5G" string(6) "ITD0TM"` and `echo $hotel->hotelCode ;` response is : ITRR5GITD0TM

Comment: i want to echo each string from the variable separately.`echo $hotel->hotelCode ;`